# Emma - Block Coverage vs Line Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, junit, emma

I have a strange scenario... while doing a EMMA coverage for UT, I get the total block coverage size more than line coverage size.

For block coverage, the total size is some 50,000 while the line coverage is out of 18,000.

I get (block-coverage-value) / 50,000 and (line-coverage-value) / 18,000 in the report.

Is it possible? How can the number of blocks be more than the number of lines in code?

btw, you can assume that I know what Block Coverage is: http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q.blockcoverage

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to get multiple blocks on the same line, for example:

```
int i = j > 0 ? j : -j;
```

contains 3 blocks (guestimate). If you like dense code blocks can outnumber the lines.

Comment: Yes, just an example, there are other ways to get multiple blocks on a single line.